# Need to enforce edge of container on nav dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm a bit flummoxed about formatting this nav (Contact dropdown) to not overflow outside the container:

http://782.2b6.myftpupload.com/

I'm sure it's because I've used position:relative a bit to move the nav around and make it stay inside the orange stripe. There'd be a lot of code to post in regard to what's going on with the nav as I'm just customizing a theme. Hoping someone can help me pinpoint what container I can target and what to code for forcing the "Contact" dropdown to come down flush against the website container, therefore showing a little below "Blog" as well rather than just busting out to the right. Help please!
[Screenshot of .sub-menu popping out of container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVc6s.jpg)

Comment: Yikes man. The -1 seems a much. This clearly isn't the production site (as the temp-domain is quite random). However, since I get point of preserving the issue for others' benefit, I'll include a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

Comment: You still need to explain this better, for example with some relevant code in the question. But I see you are editing to improve, so I've rescinded the down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by adding:

```
.sub-menu {
  right: 0;
}
```

Although doing so will apply this to each item with the `.sub-menu` class. If possible, add a new class name to that element to add the CSS above.

Comment: That's amazing, you're a legend! However, do you know why the site still has a horizontal scroll?

Comment: not exactly - but I can see that the div `.social-header` extends beyond the header. Try adding `overflow: hidden` to major elements until you see what prevents scrolling.

Comment: Still working on the damn horizontal scroll, but thanks so much @Toby, so much annoyance solved in minutes 

Comment: Can you try setting `overflow: hidden` on the div `et_menu_container` ?

Comment: That works, but then makes the drop downs disabled on hover

Comment: well, it's more of a starting point than a final solution. If that resolves the horizontal scroll issue, then something inside that div is pushing outside of it's bounds. You could possibly fix the issue by adding `overflow: hidden` to "some" element - body, for example. But the better solution is to check anything set to 100% width that also has margins, padding or something else that might affect that total width.

Comment: BOOM! Thanks so much for all the follow-up! Changing the width of that container from 100% to 98% is exactly what I needed. I need to buy you a coffee. Or beer. Or fresh squeeze OJ.          `.et_header_style_left .logo_container {
 width: 98%;
}`